# Weka: ADTree and LADTree Illegal Options Error

Tags: java, weka

Before I start my question, I should preface it by saying that the main Weka site is down, and I can't access its support pages.

I'm trying to call Weka classifiers from some automation software and I'm running into a problem - I'm calling it with options I know to be legal from the explorer GUI, but I'm getting an exception telling me that those options are illegal:

Explorer classifier path:

```
weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree -B 10 -E -3
```

My code:

```
classifier = trainWekaClassifier(matlab2weka('training', featurelabels, train), trees.ADTree', {strcat('-B 10 -E -3')});
```

The error is:

```
??? Java exception occurred:
java.lang.Exception: Illegal options: -B 10 -E -3

    at weka.core.Utils.checkForRemainingOptions(Utils.java:482)

    at weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree.setOptions(ADTree.java:1144)


Error in ==> trainWekaClassifier at 40
        wekaClassifier.setOptions(options);

Error in ==> classifier_search at 223
            classifier = trainWekaClassifier(matlab2weka('training', featurelabels,
            train), 'trees.ADTree', {strcat('-B 10 -E -3')});
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here: http://old.nabble.com/API-questions-td24569571.html

In case that website goes down again and your search has brought you here, the problem is that "-B 10" is not a valid input.  It needs to be an array of strings, {"-B", "10"}.